# How to do full integration tests in a play framework app?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4

I am trying to write test for an application written with play framework 2.4 and scala. The source is available [here](https://github.com/gitlinks/gitrank-web)

I am trying to write tests that would work with the whole stack. We are working with a neo4j database available through a REST API.

Here is my test:

```
package integration

import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.specification._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._
import setup.TestSetup

class PublicAPISpec extends Specification with BeforeEach {

  def before = TestSetup.populateNeo4JData()

  "The score feedback badge api" should {
    "deliver a correct svg file" in {
      running(FakeApplication()) {
        val svg = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/api/badges/github/test/test.svg")).get

        status(svg) must equalTo(OK)
        contentType(svg) must beSome.which(_ == "image/svg+xml")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my stack trace:

```
[info] The score feedback badge api should
[error]   ! deliver a correct svg file
[error]    There is no started application (Play.scala:71)
[error] play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:71)
[error] play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:71)
[error] play.api.Play$.current(Play.scala:71)
[error] setup.TestSetup$.setup$TestSetup$$cypher(TestSetup.scala:80)
[error] setup.TestSetup$.clearNeo4JData(TestSetup.scala:23)
[error] setup.TestSetup$.populateNeo4JData(TestSetup.scala:32)
[error] integration.PublicAPISpec.before(PublicAPISpec.scala:15)
[error] integration.PublicAPISpec.before(PublicAPISpec.scala:13)
```

**Edit** 
Turns out, like the stack trace obviously points out the major problem was in the TestSetup class. This class depended on a play application to run whereas it should not. After some refactoring, it now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do route tests you need to have the `Application` context in the test.
The test should start with

```
"deliver a correct svg file" in new WithApplication {
....
}
```

You can see more about it at the [Play's page about functional tests](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2#Testing-the-router).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however i got the exact same Exception

Comment: This is on a branch, I just pushed it: [here](https://github.com/gitlinks/gitrank-web/blob/feature/giveFeedbackBadge/test/integration/PublicAPISpec.scala) you go. Thanks for the help !

Comment: I Think I found the source of the problem which look like a dependency to play in the before method. Will update the status of this post once I have fixed it